# Logging in user through Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to log in a user through DRF view.

```
@list_route(methods=['post'])
def login(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    login_form = LoginForm(request, data=request.data or None)

    if login_form.is_valid():
        _login(request._request, login_form.get_user())
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError("login wrong")
    return Response({})
```

Above code runs without exception, but it doesn't seem to actually log in the user.

When I refresh the browser, the user is still not logged in.

How can I log in the user?

Comment: what happens in your `_login` method? Can you edit your question with the code involved?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis yeah your hunch was correct. I used from django.contrib.auth.views import login as _login. I should have used `django.contrib.auth.login`

Comment: So is it fixed now @eugene ?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis yes, I could accept if you turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the `_login()` method doesn't do what you expect.

As you mention in your your comment. you were using:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as _login
```

but this method:

> Displays the login form and handles the login action.

You should (as you do) use:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as _login
```

which:

> Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
>     have to reauthenticate on every request. 
> Note that data set during
>     the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use DRF to log people in with session.

The warning a few lines after the [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) gives you more details about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. didn't know about it